# Access custom billing field in rules using Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, emails

I have added the field `field_e_mail` to the Billing profile type in Commerce and would like to use this for sending an confirmation email to the customer (customers never log in). However, I can't for the life of me get hold of the field in rules. I've tried to use *Entity has field* in different ways, but I still can't get it to work.

What can I do to get the `field_e_mail` field from Billing into rules and use it for sending a confirmation email?

This is where I am at the moment (test@test.com is just a placeholder where I'd like to put the field_e_mail value):

```
{ "commerce_checkout_checkout_send_order_activation" : {
"LABEL" : "Send an order notification e-mail (cloned)",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "4",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "Commerce Checkout" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_checkout" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ], "field" : "commerce_customer_billing" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : {
      "entity" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing" ],
      "field" : "field_e_mail"
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
      "to" : "test@test.com",
      "subject" : "Order [commerce-order:order-number] at [site:name] test",
      "message" : "hello.",
      "from" : "no-reply@test.com",
      "language" : [ "commerce-order:state" ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

Comment: This is the right approach and should work. Did you manage to find the right commerce profile type in rules? You should use `Entity has field` on that, not on the commerce order.

Comment: @Neograph734 Right now I'm using Entity has field to look for `field_e_mail` on `commerce-order` (see initial post for export), is this correct?

Comment: Nope, the field is on the profile. So you should look it for it there. (Might even need another Entity has field to get the profile in, but I guess not.)

Comment: @Neograph734 Alright, seems like I _do_ need another Entity has field though since there's no selector with profile available currently. Do I just add multiple Entity has field conditions, or how does that work?

Comment: Yes, you can place 2 after each other. The second will have access to the new  properties 'unlocked' by the first.

Comment: @Neograph734 I'll try that then (having a bit of difficulties with wrapping my head around the hierarchy of orders, please bare with me here), if the initial entity has field is `commerce-order` with the value `commerce_customer_billing` I then "unlock" `commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing` on my second condition – this would be where I then select my field, correct? (noticed your other post, but just wanted to finish my train of thought here first).

Comment: Yes, that should be right (though I just checked my rules and I did not need the first condition and had access to `commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing` right away).

Comment: @Neograph734 Strange I'm not able to do that. Anyway, so far so good – but shouldn't `field_e_mail` show up in data selection/replacement patterns now then, or do I have to manually specify it?

Comment: Do note that you have to access it through the entire chain though. So it is `commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing:field_e_mail`. In case you were looking for it directly

Comment: @Neograph734 Aah, absolutely brilliant! I can't thank you enough for your help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added the e-mail field on the commerce profile type as you said, you should access is via the profile type as well. (It is not a property of the commerce order.)

Normally, the commerce profiles are already available when the commerce order is loaded. But you might not recognize them as such. Nothing indicates it it a profile.

For instance I have access to these profiles:

[image: profiles]

And then you can use a condition like this:

```
  { "entity_has_field" : {
      "entity" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-customer-quotation" ],
      "field" : "commerce_customer_address"
    }
  }
```